# Logical Data Model from XMI file

Tags: sybase, datamodel, powerdesigner, xmi

I want to get the logical data model from XMI file I have, is it posible through Sybase powerdesigner.

Thanks & Regards,
Yashu Vyas

Comment: AFAIK PowerDesigner imports XMI files describing OO models.

Answer (score 0):

This reply may be dated, as it's from 2006.

> Unfortunately, PowerDesigner doesn't really have a "Logical Data Model". What it does have is a Physical Data Model with a  target. So, to reverse engineer from a DBMS specific PDM to a logical PDM, you generate from PDM to PDM and select Logical as the target.

-- Mike Nicewarner [TeamSybase]

In addition, here is a link to the [PowerDesigner docs on logical data models](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38058.1600/doc/html/rad1232020009982.html).